# Importing csv data stored in a python module

Tags: python, pandas, relative-path, python-import, scientific-computing

I have a scientific computing project for which I'm running an analysis and would like some data to be kept with the python module.  I'd like the data to be 'importable' for use within a couple of examples.

The project folder hierarchy looks like this:

```
~/parent/
    setup.py
    setupegg.py
    /project
        __init__.py
        core.py
        /data
            __init__.py
            load_data.py
            somedata.csv
        /examples
            __init__.py
            ex1.py
```

I've run `python setupegg.py develop` from the project home folder so this package is importable from anywhere on my computer.  This works so far.

The file `load_data.py` looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("somedata.csv")
```

And the file `ex1.py` looks like this:

```
from test_module.data.load_data import df
def run():
    print df
```

But now when I run `from project.examples import ex1` or `from project.data import load_data` I receive an IOError message saying 'somedata.csv' does not exist.

If I add this to the preamble of the data/load_data.py file

```
import os
print os.listdir('./')
```

It prints the list of files/folder in the directory that I'm working from.

Of course, if I use absolute pathnames to the data then it will load perfectly.  How can I adjust the import statements so that reading of the csv files in the data folder does not use absolute pathnames?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the csv is in the same directory as the module that opens it then you could try using the `__file__` attribute:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "somedata.csv"))
```